# As someone currently on the Windows 8.1 Preview, how can I upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro via an iso?

Tags: windows-8, proxy, iso-image, windows-8.1

I used to have a Windows 8 Pro machine<sup>1</sup>. When the preview came out, I decided to try it, assuming that there would be a clean upgrade option after the full version came out. So I downloaded the iso from the Windows site and used the key provided to install it.

It seemed to work, though of course there was the "Windows 8.1 Pro Preview Evaluation copy" message at the bottom.

Now, as the full 8.1 is out, I got the iso and key from DreamSpark, and want to switch to it.

On mounting the iso and starting the installation, it gives me two options:

- Keep only personal files
- Keep nothing

This does not bode too well. I'd rather not lose my installed programs (apps are fine).

I do know that [I can update using the Store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-preview#), however the Store does not work behind an authenticated university proxy<sup>2</sup>. So my only option is to update from the iso, which may lead to the loss of my programs.

How can I do this without losing my programs?

(If anyone thinks they have a way of fixing the Store to work with an auth proxy in 8.1, let me know in a comment and I'll ask it separately)

<sup>1. Dual booted with Ubuntu with UEFI turned off, but that probably isn't relevant.</sup>

<sup>2. The fix for this via CCProxy doesn't work anymore for some reason; and though I hear that 8.1 has better proxy support, I haven't managed to set it up so that it understands the proxy.</sup>

Comment: `assuming that there would be a clean upgrade option after the full version came out` - that was a bad assumption.  Almost every evaluation includes notes from Microsoft saying that you will not be able to convert from a preview/evaluation release to a full release. The evaluation releases also tend to come with warnings reminding you to make backups and that you shouldn't use them on a production system.

Comment: @Zoredache Yeah, I do have data backups, just didn't think of doing a full image backup. If worse comes to worse I don't mind reinstalling stuff -- I have a copy of all the installers and keys, so I decided to take that chance. Just hoping for a way out without that :)